# Using Observable.from and flatMap to perform operation on each item in an Array, onComplete is not being called

Tags: android, reactive-programming, rx-java

I'm using Rx-Java to perform an api call for each item in an array. I want the OnComplete action to be called once all operations have completed but it is not being called. The operations on the array items do complete successfully.

```
public Observable<User> report(Long[] userIds) {
    return Observable.from(userIds).flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<User>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<User> call(Long id) {
            return reportSpam(id);
        }
    });
}

public Observable<User> report(final Long id) {
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<User>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super User> subscriber) {
            try {
                twitter.report(id);
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                subscriber.onError(e);
            }
        }
    });
}

final Long[] usersIds = selectedToUsersIds();

report(usersIds).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new Action1<User>() {
        @Override
        public void call(User user) {
            //nothing to do here, don't even need the User
        }
    }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Throwable throwable) {
        //handle this
        }
    }, new Action0() {
        @Override
        public void call() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.reported_for_spam, usersIds.length), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `subscriber.onCompleted()` in `Observable<User> report(final Long id)`. An `Observable` should always call `onCompleted` or `onError` at the end of the stream.